# Reusing a Schengen visa for another purpose

Tags: visas, schengen

I am an Indian citizen and I had visited Poland for a week in April and that Schengen visa  (multiple entry) is valid till end of August. I would like to visit Denmark for a month in June. Can I do that ? I have an invitation from the company in Denmark.

Comment: Is it a multi-entry visa?

Comment: Yes, it is. But I have read somewhere that you should get the visa from the country where you are going to stay for maximum days.

Comment: @Jack That's why having a multiple-entry visa is important. If it was a single-entry visa, using it for something else means that the info you submitted is not correct anymore (i.e. you are not doing the trip you said you wanted to do). But if it's a multiple-entry visa and you have already used it according to your initial plan then reusing it is fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Beside the period of validity, there are two other things you have to check to make sure your visa is still valid:

- The number of allowed entries
- The maximum stay (it is to be understood as [a grand total across all stays under this visa](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/46843/schengen-visa-2-entries-60-days/46852#46852), except if it is “90” and the visa is valid for more than six months, in which case it means [up to 90 days in any 180-day period](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/13183/about-schengen-90-180-rule))

If your new stay would be allowed while respecting all these limitations then you can certainly do it with your current visa.

In particular, having a multiple-entry visa means that you have a lot more flexibility. You are only expected to submit a detailed itinerary and proof of travel insurance for the first journey on the visa and after that it's [completely fine to use it for other purposes or destinations](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/13362/should-my-first-trip-be-to-the-country-which-issued-my-schengen-visa/44782#44782).

You should however carry all the documents you would need for a fresh visa application (e.g. itinerary, invitation, travel insurance). You will probably not need them but that would help showing your trip is completely legitimate if any doubt arises at the border.

Comment: @ Relaxed, thanks for your answer. I have a multiple entries visa and since I stayed for a week in Poland in April, I can stay a month from June 15th to July 15th in Denmark (90/180 rules). I guess I won't have any problem.

Comment: @Jack I don't know if I was clear, the 90/180 only applies if the sticker says “90” under “maximum stay”. It's often the case for multiple-entry visas but not always so you need to check that.